# Problem opening hdri from hdri heaven

Tags: shaders, light, hdri, matcaps

When i am loading hdri setup from hdri heaven, it is not showing up.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the time to properly format your question including links and embedded images and thoroughly explaining the issue . Also remove any extraneous text like "please help" or other content not essential to answer the question

Comment: You need to switch your shader to "World" and connect the HDRI through an Environment Texture. See here - https://ibb.co/hBS6fX7

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6